# Bewildering "The server was not found or was not accessible." error but only for some users

Tags: .net, iis, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out an issue in an IIS web app.  On the surface it seems like a simple security issue, but, it's not.

It was working about a year ago the last time I had to do changes to it.  The change I made this time was minor, but, when I deployed to our development server, I started getting the following error:

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
 Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Seems pretty straightforward.  The obvious answer was over the last year that something changed and now the database server cannot be found.  Here's the problem: I get the error when I try to access the web site, but, other people don't.  Still seems like a simple rights issue except the connection string is using a specific User ID and Password to access the database. The business owner who has been on the project a number of years, is not able to get in either.  The business analyst who joined the team in the last year, is able to get in.   A test user I created in the last month is able to get in.

The application connects to two separate databases.  Both connections use the same user and password.  I installed SSMS on the server and I am able to connect to both databases as myself and the user from the connection strings.

I went through the permissions in the application folder under wwwroot and I have full rights.  The ApplicationPool has a specific user assigned.  That user has full rights to the folders also.  I am an administrator on the VM, but the business owner is not, furthermore, another person that is an administrator on the VM is able to get into the site without getting the error.

The .Net Framework 4.5 MVC web app is deployed under IIS 8.5.96 on Win Server 2012 R2 VM.

Web.Config-----------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
       <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />


    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->

</configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxxx.csdl|res://*/xxxx.ssdl|res://*/xxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxx;initial catalog=xxxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" name="Entities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxxx.csdl|res://*/xxxx.ssdl|res://*/xxxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" name="xxxxEntities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="100240" executionTimeout="1200" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
<authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <customErrors mode="Off" />   
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="http to https" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Angularjs Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(vendor/.*|src/.*|api/.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 127" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xxx\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://xxxx/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
           <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://xxxx/" responseMode="Redirect" /> 
        </httpErrors>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
            <clear />
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="everyone.*" />
      </audienceUris>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="xxx" name="Okta" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>

  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>

      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="xxx" realm="xxxx" />

      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" path="/" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of firewall issue? Try deactivating it!

Comment: Does request appear in access logs / http error log or windows event viewer?

Comment: @Hackerman - I think if it was a firewall issue it would affect all users of the site.

Comment: @MisterSmith - I have not looked at the access logs.  I have looked at the windows event viewer, but, I didn't see anything.  That doesn't mean it's not there.  I'll take another look.

Comment: Last Friday I tried creating another  .NetFr 4.5 MVC app and used the exact same connect strings with EntityFramework.  One difference is the new site uses Windows Auth, but, the one I'm having problems with uses Okta.  No answer yet, but, I think I have a few ideas to try now.